# Is it possible to set a Windows command line variable by reading a text file?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a one line text file that will be created daily and was wondering if one could use `SET` and `TYPE` (unless someone has a easier Windows command line utility) to define a Windows command line variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I set an environment variable using the value from a file?

You don't need [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) to do this. Instead use the `<` [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) operator.

The following command line using [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) will do what you want:

```
set /p variable=<file.txt
```

Notes:

- `command < filename` will type a text file (`filename`) and pass the text to `command`

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

Answer (score 2):

You can [redirect](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) a file as input into a [`SET`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb490998.aspx) command that's prompting for user input.

So something like:

`set /P myVariable= < myFile.txt`